# twitter return datetime to datetime format in python

Tags: python, datetime

```
def _datetime(date_str):
    r=datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(date_str,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fp = open( 'csk.csv', 'rb' )
    reader = csv.reader( fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\' )

    c=''
    a=[]
    sent=[]
    dates=[]
    for row in reader:
        c=row[1] #twitter datetime in these format Wed Apr 22 14:29:00 +0000 2015
        b=_datetime(c)
        a.append(b)        
    print a
```

It is giving format error when i tried these, even many previous questions supported the above striptime format, I want actually pass these parameter to plot graph.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: row[1] is twitter datetime in Wed Apr 22 14:29:00 +0000 2015 format and want it in datetime format

Comment: I would edit that into your question if I were you, because it's rather hard to discern any meaningful question from a block of code.

Comment: It is giving error ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'

Comment: ***Edit this information*** into your question, please.

Comment: it works for me with the string you mentioned ... I'm guessing the row[1] is not EXACTLY the string you mentioned

Comment: Have you tried `datutils.parser.parse` ?

Comment: @mdurant you mean `dateutil.parser.parse`?

Comment: Have you printed row[1] to confirm that it's definitely what you think it is? CSVs can start with one row that just has header text labelling all the columns rather than the data you're trying to access.

Comment: I have checked it is datetime in following format Wed Apr 22 14:29:00 +0000 2015

Comment: What error do you get? (provide the full traceback). What is the corresonding `row[1]`? (`print(repr(c))`)

Answer (score 0):

```
def _datetime(date_str):
    r=datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(date_str,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fp = open( 'csk.csv', 'rb' )
    reader = csv.reader( fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\' )

    c=''
    a=[]
    sent=[]
    dates=[]
    for row in reader:
        c=row[1] #twitter datetime in these format Wed Apr 22 14:29:00 +0000 2015
        try:b=_datetime(c)
        except:pass
        a.append(b)        
    print a
```

just adding try except block solved the issue

Comment: don't use bare `except:` it may match too much e.g., `KeyboardInterrupt`. Catch more specific error such as `except ValueError:`. Add logging for debugging purposes.